# Why does my postgresql stored procedure proceduces ERROR: type with OID 0 does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure with a (one) text array as INOUT-Parameter ( I'm using PostgreSQL 12 )

Can somebody help me ? The C-Sourcecode produces an error in psql:

```
DO 
$$
DECLARE 
  test text[];
BEGIN
  test := '{"x","y","z"}';
  CALL ptest( test );
  RAISE NOTICE '%', test;
END
$$
;
```

ERROR:  type with OID 0 does not exist

CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CALL ptest( test )"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at CALL

Declaring:

```
create or replace procedure ptest(INOUT text[] ) as 'ptest.so' language 'c';
postgres=# \df
List of functions
Schema |  Name   | Result data type |                            Argument data types                            | Type 
--------+---------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------
 public | ptest   |                  | INOUT text[]                                                              | proc
```

Thanks a lot !

The C-Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "funcapi.h"
#include "array.h"

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

Datum ptest(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(ptest);

Datum
ptest ( PG_FUNCTION_ARGS )
{ 
   ArrayType       * arg_arr;

   arg_arr = PG_GETARG_ARRAYTYPE_P( 0 );

   PG_RETURN_ARRAYTYPE_P( arg_arr );

   // TEXTOID = 25 the following code produces the same error:
   // PG_RETURN_ARRAYTYPE_P( construct_empty_array( 25 ));
}
```

Comment: It seems that only composite types can  be returned in procedures like : return ( HeapTupleGetDatum( resultTuple ) );